Pandas "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous." with Lambda
I have a df for which I want to patch the negative values (replace them with mean of the group).
I'm confused as to why the following throws an error:
df['patched_vals']=df.groupby(['grps'])['vals'].transform(lambda x: x if (x >0) else x.mean())

While this works fine:
df['patched_vals']=df.groupby('grps').vals.transform(lambda x: x +(x.mean()-x)*(x<0))


Think carefully: when the code lambda x: x if (x >0) else x.mean() is used, what do you expect x to look like each time? (Hint: it's in the error message.) What kind of result do you expect if you supply that x to x > 0? (Hint: it will be the same as the answer to the first question.) Do you see why it wouldn't work to use that result with if, but would work to use that result with other mathematical operations? If not, please check the link.

The key difference between the codes is if/else. transform is perfectly happy to return a Series (therefore the valid second code), but if requires a scalar, which x > 0 is not.
